# Teradata SQL PDCR query- filtering out to get only Unique Queries with High CPU rank ( Database Performance tuning )

Tags: sql, database, teradata, database-performance, olap

I am running a standard Query joining PDCRLogtbl with PDCRSQLTbl for pulling up high impact CPU. I am sure a similar one has been used / seen before , most places . Nothing exiting about it

```
    SELECT  
    RANK(ImpactCPU) AS CPURank
   ,USERNAME
   ,sessionid
   ,AcctString 
   ,/*--including additionally */ Hashrow ( qrytext)  Unique_SQL_ID
    /* qrytext comes from SQLtbl.SQLTextinfo if available or its    logtbl.querytext*/  
   <col list>
     from 
    (SELECT a.USERNAME
      , sessionid
    --  , a.logdate                 
      , a.ProcId
      , a.QueryId
      , a.expandacctstring
       <calculations for CPU skew, Impact CPU , other skew's here>
      from PDCRinfo.DBQLogtbl
      where <filters here> 
      group by clause 
      ) a 
      LOJ ( sel < col list> from FROM   PDCRInfo.DBQLSQLTbl s 
      where <filters here> ) s on <join cols >
      order by  CPURank  asc ,  spoolusage desc
```

o/p is something like this

```
CPUrank Username <other cols> impactCPU Querytext  Unique_SQL_ID
1       JohnD                 50000     Sel foobar   1F-0C-A1-EB
5       JaneD                 60000     sel yadaya   A9-CE-55-1D
6       JohnD                 35000     Sel foobar   1F-0C-A1-EB
9       JohnD                 25000     Sel foobar   1F-0C-A1-EB
10      BobD                  24000     sel Daddy    6E-1C-18-08
11      JaneD                 23000     sel yadaya   A9-CE-55-1D
12      JohnD                 22500     Sel foobar   1F-0C-A1-EB
15      GeorgeD               22400     sel holahu   9B-4A-D1-F4
```

Here the **SAME** `Unique_SQL_ID` shows up in varying spots 1 , 6 and 9.I just want the 1st Instance - one with the `highest CPU rank` to show up and rest of 'em ignored. After all its the same SQL being run over on different occasions. 

 
Desired

```
CPUrank Username <other cols> impactCPU Querytext  Unique_SQL_ID
    1       JohnD                 50000     Sel foobar   1F-0C-A1-EB
    5       JaneD                 60000     sel yadaya   A9-CE-55-1D
    10      BobD                  24000     sel Daddy    6E-1C-18-08
    15      GeorgeD               22400     sel holahu   9B-4A-D1-F4
```

What should I be doing ? maybe put in a qualifying or some similar filter ... some sort of an OLAP function to pass those rows through that will filter em out. I guess I could do it through an extra pass of all those rows through a `dt` but wanted to see if there's a simple filter I can stick in there that can do the job just as well 
 Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this filter at the end of the query ,  will give the fix .

```
  qualify 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Unique_SQL_ID
                               ORDER BY impactCPU DESC
                          )
                             = 1
```

The Original answer elegantly gave the `row_num () over (PARTITION BY Unique_SQL_ID ORDER BY impactCPU DESC )` which is exactly what I was looking for. But this being an Ordered Analytical Function - you can't stick it in the `where` clause or `having` either. This is just a minor modification. The gist of the answer given by  MatBailie is abs. right .  Thanks Mat

Comment: The Original answer elegantly gave the `row_num () over (PARTITION BY Unique_SQL_ID ORDER BY impactCPU DESC )` which is exactly what I was looking for. But this being an `Ordered Analytical Function` - you can't stick it in the `where` clause or `having` either. This is just a minor modification. The gist of the answer given by MatBailie is abs. right . I edited it to reflect just this minor fix . Thanks Mat !